# Safety/health hazards: working with 2-aminobenzimidazole, iminoesters, and 1,3,5-triazine

Tags: organic-chemistry, safety

How dangerous is it working with 2-aminobenzimidazole, iminoesters and 1,3,5-triazine? Has there been any cases of health problems recorded concerning those three compounds?

Comment: You should edit your question immediately - eliminate personal info and state problem more precisely.

Comment: I wanted to do it myself but wasn't sure how to state it. IMO, if promoter gives you such work, you shouldn't worry too much - you need to be cautious in lab on daily basis and probably worked with more dangerous stuff not even knowing about it.

Comment: Your previous revision stated that you studied some stuff about their hazard $\ldots$ could you provide a link to what you studied?

Comment: Uhm. This is really really weird. You want to quit your chemistry study because you worry about lab safety? Laboratories are generally safer than freeways and should pose no hazard when being properly guided, which is in principle what a university is for. I'm not sure whether I believe the story of yours. It's also none of my business. Just saying that we are not here to help you synthesize your own pharmaceuticals...

Comment: @user19185 - If you are very concerned about how to proceed if you believe your research has become hazardous to your health, you could ask a question at [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com). I would avoid personal details and the specifics of your research so that the question could be general enough to be useful. Also, be clear that you are not looking for legal or medical advise. The internet is a terrible place to find either.

Answer (score 4):

Looking up the chemical you're working with is always a good idea, but you need to look closer and evaluate the specific danger those chemicals present to you. What you want to look at are the danger symbols and the hazard and precautionary statements. Those will tell you the specific dangers a chemical presents.

If you look up your first substance, 2-aminobenzimidazole, it looks pretty tame for organic chemistry standards. It has an exclamation mark as danger symbol, which doesn't tell you much, but the absence of a skull and crossbones and a health hazard symbol tell you that this probably won't kill you immediately. This doesn't mean the stuff is harmless, but it is also not extremely toxic. If you look at the hazard statements of this chemical you'll find that you shouldn't get it into your eyes, on your skin or breathe it. All of that is a good idea when working with any chemical, and this is exactly what you should learn when studying chemistry. This is a really tame chemical compared to a lot of stuff organic chemists work regularly with, but you still should avoid exposing yourself to it.

Your second item is an entire category of chemicals, I'll skip it for this reason. The third one is a bit more dangerous than the first one, it has a corrosive and a health hazard danger symbol. You want to avoid contact with it, but that's what all your protective equipment like safety goggles, your lab coat and your fume hood are for.

I'm not saying those chemicals are harmless, they're not. But they are less dangerous than many other common chemicals in an organic chemistry lab.

Comment: I've answered this in part based on an older revision of the question, as the newer one doesn't have enought context.